# checkbox condition leads to another page

Tags: php

I want to create conditions on the checkbox.

if you select 1 then it will be to his next page
If you select 2 and 3 it will be to a thank you page

can help me

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="1">1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="2">2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="3">3

<?php
if (
        (
            ($number == '1') && ($number == '2')
        ) 
            || 
        (
            ($number == '1') && ($number == '3')
        ) 
            || 
        (
            ($number == '1') && ($number == '2') && ($number == '3')
        )
    )

      {
        header("Location: next.php"); /* Redirect browser */
      } else {
        header("location: thank-you.php");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply process the result of the form and determine what action to take. For example, your form could be:

```
<form method="post" action="processform.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="1">1 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="2">2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="number[]" id="" value="3">3 <br />
</form>
```

Then in the processform.php file, see what values are selected and take the appropriate action. For example by putting all the selections in a glued string and then use a switch to handle that:

```
<?php
// Set the value to an empty string initially (meaning nothing was selected)
$value = '';

// Determine the selected values and "glue" them together as a numeric string
foreach ($_POST['number'] as $number) {
   $value .= $number;
}

// Now, take the appropriate action
switch ($value) {
    case '1':
        // Only checkbox 1 was selected
        header('Location: page-1.php');
        break;
    case '12':
        // Checkbox 1 and 2 were selected
        header('Location: page-12.php');
        break;
    case '13':
        // Checkbox 1 and 3 were selected
        header('Location: page-13.php');
        break;
    // Keep doing this for all the combinations you want
    // If none of these are triggered, the default action below will be...
    default:
        // Either nothing was selected, or something not listed above
        header('Location: try-again.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to access GET/POST variables via register globals - please don't do that. Use `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending on the way you pass the data from the form). Also, checked values will be stored in an array, so you can't just compare an array to a value. Use `in_array()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Example:
`if (in_array('1', $_POST['number'])) { ... }`

Comment: i have use  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { ... } but not working